# Join function in JavaScript with separator not showing at the end for arrays with unknown number of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, separator

I am new to JavaScript and I have encountered a little problem while using the join function. I have an array with an unknown number of elements and I want to print it with separators between each two elements using join. I want to get something like this: `a/b/c/d` with '/' being the separator. The problem is that I get one last separator at the end, like this: `a/b/c/d/`. How can I get rid of this?
Here is my code:

```js
var makePath;

function makePath(separator) {
  let comp = []
  return function(element) {
    comp.push(element)
    return comp.join(separator)
  }
}

var main = function() {
  var p1 = makePath("/");
  p1("One");
  p1("Two");
  p1("Three");

  window.console.log("p1:" + p1());
}

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

in your `console.log` statement you are invoking `p1()` with an empty argument. That is what is adding the trailing delimiter to your string. You would want to store the result of the final invocation and use that instead.

```js
var makePath;
function makePath(separator)
{   
  let comp = []
  return function(element)
  {
    comp.push(element)
    return comp.join(separator)
  }
}




var main = function()   
{
var p1 = makePath("/");
p1("One"); 
p1("Two"); 
var x = p1("Three");//store the result of p1('three')

window.console.log("p1:" + x );//print it out
}
main();
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you call `p1()` without an argument, you're actually performing `p1(undefined)`. Therefore your array looks like this : `["One", "Two", "Three", undefined]` and gets joined as `One/Two/Three/`

Demonstration :

```js
var makePath;

function makePath(separator) {
  let comp = []
  return function(element) {
    console.log(`pushing "${element}" to array`)
    comp.push(element)
    return comp.join(separator)
  }
}

var main = function() {
  var p1 = makePath("/");
  p1("One");
  p1("Two");
  p1("Three");

  window.console.log("p1:" + p1());
}

main()
```

Solution : if no argument is passed, don't push it to the array :

```js
var makePath;

function makePath(separator) {
  let comp = []
  return function(element) {
    if(element) comp.push(element)
    return comp.join(separator)
  }
}

var main = function() {
  var p1 = makePath("/");
  p1("One");
  p1("Two");
  p1("Three");

  window.console.log("p1:" + p1());
}

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not only check for the `undefined` param? and that way you execute the function `join` only when you need to build the string.

```js
function makePath(separator) {
  let comp = []
  return function(element) {
    if (element) comp.push(element);    
    return comp.join(separator);
  }
}

var main = function() {
  let pathify = makePath("/");
  pathify("One");
  pathify("Two");
  pathify("Three");

  window.console.log("Path:", pathify());
}

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

just add `.replace` which will remove last `/` with this regexp `/\/$/`

```js
var makePath;
function makePath(separator)
{   
  let comp = []
  return function(element)
  {
    comp.push(element)
    return comp.join(separator).replace(/\/$/,"")
  }
}




var main = function()   
{
var p1 = makePath("/");
p1("One"); 
p1("Two"); 
p1("Three");

window.console.log("p1:" + p1() );
}
main();
```

Comment: This works but is not the advised way to solve this problem. Instead of solving it, it is better to *avoid* it.

Comment: why this is not advised way? and why I got downvote? I gave the man an working example

Comment: "prevention is better than cure". See the other answers that look at prevention. NB: something working is not synonym for something good.